# How to specify default options in a checkbox field using Field API

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to add a checkbox field to user entities using the FIELD API (in function MYMODULE_install() )

I can create the field, but I can't pre-load it with the desired default values.

Where my code is wrong ?

```
$default_notification_field_name = "field_notification_defaults";
if(!field_info_field($default_notification_field_name))   { // check if the field already exists.

    field_create_field(
        array(
            'field_name' => $default_notification_field_name,
            'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
            'type' => 'list_text',
            'settings' => array(
                'allowed_values' => array(
                    'group' => t('Groups to which you subscribe'),
                    'content' => t('Authored content'),
                    'comment' => t('Replies to your comments')
                )
            ),
        )
    );

    field_create_instance(
        array(
            'field_name' => $default_notification_field_name,
            'entity_type' => 'user',
            'bundle' => 'user',
            'label' => t('Default settings for notifications'), 
            'description' => t('Select the ​​default notification options for the groups to which you subscribe, the contents you send and the replies to (your) comments. These default options can then be modified on a per-group, content or comment bases.'),
            'required' => FALSE,
            'widget' => array(
                'type' => 'options_buttons',
            ),
            'default_value' => array('content','comment')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this for your instance creation:

```
field_create_instance(
  array(
    'field_name' => $default_notification_field_name,
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'bundle' => 'user',
    'label' => t('Default settings for notifications'), 
    'description' => t('Select the ​​default notification options for the groups to which you subscribe, the contents you send and the replies to (your) comments. These default options can then be modified on a per-group, content or comment bases.'),
    'required' => FALSE,
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'options_buttons',
    ),
    'default_value' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'comment',
      ),
      1 => array(
        'value' => 'content',
      ),
    ),
  ));
```

To assist you in knowing the array structure, try this:

1. Install the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module
2. Go to the page /devel/php on your site
3. Run this code to see all field information on your site:

```
// Show all fields.
dpm(field_info_fields());
// Show all field instances.
dpm(field_info_instances());
```